How to change the status of invite in play console for fastlane service email id from GCP. I'm trying to configure fastlane with my play store

I've followed the exact steps given to create service account, enable google play store API, give admin access to service email id etc.
Does it automatically get accepted or there is some option to accept it?
There is no documentation regarding this. I followed this https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/ but nowhere does it mention that it automatically gets accepted.
